# Unable to retrieve data from mysql database with spring boot

Tags: java, html, mysql, database, thymeleaf

I am trying to store and retrieve data from MySQL database with spring boot and thymeleaf. The thing keeps giving me error even if I added the data into the database manually, I cant still retrieve it. Some of the error that I got is this "2022-04-17 22:03:37.821 ERROR 2500 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] s.e.ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration$StaticView : Cannot render error page for request [/countries] as the response has already been committed. As a result, the response may have the wrong status code." Another one is "
Caused by: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E: Property or field 'id' cannot be found on object of type 'com.elijahukeme.PropertiesManagementSystem.model.Country' - maybe not public or not valid?"

```
Here is my model class.
    
    @Entity
    @Data
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class)
    public class Country {
    
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        private Integer id;
        private String code;
        private String capital;
        private String description;
        private String nationality;
        private String continent;
    
        @OneToMany(mappedBy = "country")
        private List<State> states;
    }

Here is my Repository 
@Repository
public interface CountryRepository extends JpaRepository<Country,Integer> {
}

Here is my Service Class
@Service
public class CountryService {

    @Autowired
    private CountryRepository countryRepository;

    public List<Country> getAllCountry() {
        return countryRepository.findAll();
    }
    public void saveCountryInfo(Country country){
        countryRepository.save(country);
    }
}

    
Here is the controller
    
    
    @Controller
    public class CountryController {
        @Autowired
        private CountryService countryService;
    
        
        @GetMapping("/countries")
        public String getCountry(Model model){
            List<Country> countryList = countryService.getAllCountry();
            model.addAttribute("countries",countryList);
    
            return "country";
        }
       @PostMapping("/countries/addNew")
        public String saveInfo(Country country){
            countryService.saveCountryInfo(country);
            return "redirect:/countries";
        }
    }

    
This is the html page that should return the data
    
      <section class="section dashboard">
        <div class="row">
    
          <!-- Left side columns -->
    
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-12">
    
              <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
              <!-- Image background -->
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#addModal" data-whatever="@mdo">Add A Country</button>
               <h1>List of Country</h1>
                  <table class="table">
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                      <th>Id</th>
                      <th>Code</th>
                      <th>Capital</th>
                      <th>Description</th>
                      <th>Nationality</th>
                      <th>Continent</th>
                      <th>Actions</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    <tr th:each="country:${countries}">
                      <td th:text="${country.id}"></td>
                      <td th:text="${country.code}">Code</td>
                      <td th:text="${country.capital}">Capital</td>
                      <td th:text="${country.description}">Description</td>
                      <td th:text="${country.nationality}">Nationality</td>
                      <td th:text="${country.continent}">Continent</td>
                      <td>
                        <div class="btn-group">
                        <a class="btn btn-primary" id="editButton">Edit</a>
                        </div>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                    </tbody>
                  </table>
    
                </div><!-- End of Image background -->
        </div><!-- End Left side columns -->
        </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
    
    
Here is the error message from the console
    
   Caused by: org.attoparser.ParseException: Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "country.id" (template: "country" - line 547, col 23)
    at org.attoparser.MarkupParser.parseDocument(MarkupParser.java:393) ~[attoparser-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.attoparser.MarkupParser.parse(MarkupParser.java:257) ~[attoparser-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.parse(AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.java:230) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.14.RELEASE.jar:3.0.14.RELEASE]
    ... 48 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "country.id" (template: "country" - line 547, col 23)
    at org.thymeleaf.spring5.expression.SPELVariableExpressionEvaluator.evaluate(SPELVariableExpressionEvaluator.java:292) ~[thymeleaf-spring5-3.0.14.RELEASE.jar:3.0.14.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.VariableExpression.executeVariableExpression(VariableExpression.java:166) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.14.RELEASE.jar:3.0.14.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.SimpleExpression.executeSimple(SimpleExpression.java:66) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.14.RELEASE.jar:3.0.14.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.Expression.execute(Expression.java:109) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.14.RELEASE.jar:3.0.14.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.Expression.execute(Expression.java:138) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.14.RELEASE.jar:3.0.14.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.processor.AbstractStandardExpressionAttributeTagProcessor.doProcess(AbstractStandardExpressionAttributeTagProcessor.java:144) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.14.RELEASE.jar:3.0.14.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.processor.element.AbstractAttributeTagProcessor.doProcess(AbstractAttributeTagProcessor.java:74) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.14.RELEASE.jar:3.0.14.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.processor.element.AbstractElementTagProcessor.process(AbstractElementTagProcessor.java:95) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.14.RELEASE.jar:3.0.14.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.util.ProcessorConfigurationUtils$ElementTagProcessorWrapper.process(ProcessorConfigurationUtils.java:633) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.14.RELEASE.jar:3.0.14.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.ProcessorTemplateHandler.handleOpenElement(ProcessorTemplateHandler.java:1314) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.14.RELEASE.jar:3.0.14.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.OpenElementTag.beHandled(OpenElementTag.java:205) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.14.RELEASE.jar:3.0.14.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.Model.process(Model.java:282) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.14.RELEASE.jar:3.0.14.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.Model.process(Model.java:290) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.14.RELEASE.jar:3.0.14.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.IteratedGatheringModelProcessable.processIterationModel(IteratedGatheringModelProcessable.java:367) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.14.RELEASE.jar:3.0.14.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.IteratedGatheringModelProcessable.process(IteratedGatheringModelProcessable.java:221) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.14.RELEASE.jar:3.0.14.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.ProcessorTemplateHandler.handleCloseElement(ProcessorTemplateHandler.java:1640) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.14.RELEASE.jar:3.0.14.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateHandlerAdapterMarkupHandler.handleCloseElementEnd(TemplateHandlerAdapterMarkupHandler.java:388) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.14.RELEASE.jar:3.0.14.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.InlinedOutputExpressionMarkupHandler$InlineMarkupAdapterPreProcessorHandler.handleCloseElementEnd(InlinedOutputExpressionMarkupHandler.java:322) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.14.RELEASE.jar:3.0.14.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.inline.OutputExpressionInlinePreProcessorHandler.handleCloseElementEnd(OutputExpressionInlinePreProcessorHandler.java:220) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.14.RELEASE.jar:3.0.14.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.InlinedOutputExpressionMarkupHandler.handleCloseElementEnd(InlinedOutputExpressionMarkupHandler.java:164) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.14.RELEASE.jar:3.0.14.RELEASE]
    at org.attoparser.HtmlElement.handleCloseElementEnd(HtmlElement.java:169) ~[attoparser-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.attoparser.HtmlMarkupHandler.handleCloseElementEnd(HtmlMarkupHandler.java:412) ~[attoparser-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.attoparser.MarkupEventProcessorHandler.handleCloseElementEnd(MarkupEventProcessorHandler.java:473) ~[attoparser-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.attoparser.ParsingElementMarkupUtil.parseCloseElement(ParsingElementMarkupUtil.java:201) ~[attoparser-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.attoparser.MarkupParser.parseBuffer(MarkupParser.java:725) ~[attoparser-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.attoparser.MarkupParser.parseDocument(MarkupParser.java:301) ~[attoparser-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    ... 50 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E: Property or field 'id' cannot be found on object of type 'com.elijah.profile.management.system.model.Country' - maybe not public or not valid?
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.readProperty(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:217) ~[spring-expression-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.getValueInternal(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:104) ~[spring-expression-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.access$000(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:51) ~[spring-expression-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference$AccessorLValue.getValue(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:406) ~[spring-expression-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.CompoundExpression.getValueInternal(CompoundExpression.java:92) ~[spring-expression-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.SpelNodeImpl.getValue(SpelNodeImpl.java:112) ~[spring-expression-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpression.getValue(SpelExpression.java:337) ~[spring-expression-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.thymeleaf.spring5.expression.SPELVariableExpressionEvaluator.evaluate(SPELVariableExpressionEvaluator.java:265) ~[thymeleaf-spring5-3.0.14.RELEASE.jar:3.0.14.RELEASE]
    ... 75 common frames omitted

2022-04-20 16:58:24.352 ERROR 3036 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: An error happened during template parsing (template: "class path resource [templates/country.html]")] with root cause

org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E: Property or field 'id' cannot be found on object of type 'com.elijah.profile.management.system.model.Country' - maybe not public or not valid?
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.readProperty(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:217) ~[spring-expression-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.getValueInternal(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:104) ~[spring-expression-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.access$000(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:51) ~[spring-expression-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference$AccessorLValue.getValue(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:406) ~[spring-expression-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.CompoundExpression.getValueInternal(CompoundExpression.java:92) ~[spring-expression-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.SpelNodeImpl.getValue(SpelNodeImpl.java:112) ~[spring-expression-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpression.getValue(SpelExpression.java:337) ~[spring-expression-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.thymeleaf.spring5.expression.SPELVariableExpressionEvaluator.evaluate(SPELVariableExpressionEvaluator.java:265) ~[thymeleaf-spring5-3.0.14.RELEASE.jar:3.0.14.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.VariableExpression.executeVariableExpression(VariableExpression.java:166) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.14.RELEASE.jar:3.0.14.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.SimpleExpression.executeSimple(SimpleExpression.java:66) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.14.RELEASE.jar:3.0.14.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.Expression.execute(Expression.java:109) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.14.RELEASE.jar:3.0.14.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.Expression.execute(Expression.java:138) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.14.RELEASE.jar:3.0.14.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.processor.AbstractStandardExpressionAttributeTagProcessor.doProcess(AbstractStandardExpressionAttributeTagProcessor.java:144) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.14.RELEASE.jar:3.0.14.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.processor.element.AbstractAttributeTagProcessor.doProcess(AbstractAttributeTagProcessor.java:74) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.14.RELEASE.jar:3.0.14.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.processor.element.AbstractElementTagProcessor.process(AbstractElementTagProcessor.java:95) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.14.RELEASE.jar:3.0.14.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.util.ProcessorConfigurationUtils$ElementTagProcessorWrapper.process(ProcessorConfigurationUtils.java:633) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.14.RELEASE.jar:3.0.14.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.ProcessorTemplateHandler.handleOpenElement(ProcessorTemplateHandler.java:1314) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.14.RELEASE.jar:3.0.14.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.OpenElementTag.beHandled(OpenElementTag.java:205) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.14.RELEASE.jar:3.0.14.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.Model.process(Model.java:282) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.14.RELEASE.jar:3.0.14.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.Model.process(Model.java:290) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.14.RELEASE.jar:3.0.14.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.IteratedGatheringModelProcessable.processIterationModel(IteratedGatheringModelProcessable.java:367) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.14.RELEASE.jar:3.0.14.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.IteratedGatheringModelProcessable.process(IteratedGatheringModelProcessable.java:221) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.14.RELEASE.jar:3.0.14.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.ProcessorTemplateHandler.handleCloseElement(ProcessorTemplateHandler.java:1640) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.14.RELEASE.jar:3.0.14.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateHandlerAdapterMarkupHandler.handleCloseElementEnd(TemplateHandlerAdapterMarkupHandler.java:388) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.14.RELEASE.jar:3.0.14.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.InlinedOutputExpressionMarkupHandler$InlineMarkupAdapterPreProcessorHandler.handleCloseElementEnd(InlinedOutputExpressionMarkupHandler.java:322) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.14.RELEASE.jar:3.0.14.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.inline.OutputExpressionInlinePreProcessorHandler.handleCloseElementEnd(OutputExpressionInlinePreProcessorHandler.java:220) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.14.RELEASE.jar:3.0.14.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.InlinedOutputExpressionMarkupHandler.handleCloseElementEnd(InlinedOutputExpressionMarkupHandler.java:164) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.14.RELEASE.jar:3.0.14.RELEASE]
    at org.attoparser.HtmlElement.handleCloseElementEnd(HtmlElement.java:169) ~[attoparser-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.attoparser.HtmlMarkupHandler.handleCloseElementEnd(HtmlMarkupHandler.java:412) ~[attoparser-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.attoparser.MarkupEventProcessorHandler.handleCloseElementEnd(MarkupEventProcessorHandler.java:473) ~[attoparser-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.attoparser.ParsingElementMarkupUtil.parseCloseElement(ParsingElementMarkupUtil.java:201) ~[attoparser-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.attoparser.MarkupParser.parseBuffer(MarkupParser.java:725) ~[attoparser-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.attoparser.MarkupParser.parseDocument(MarkupParser.java:301) ~[attoparser-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.attoparser.MarkupParser.parse(MarkupParser.java:257) ~[attoparser-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.parse(AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.java:230) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.14.RELEASE.jar:3.0.14.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.parseStandalone(AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.java:100) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.14.RELEASE.jar:3.0.14.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateManager.parseAndProcess(TemplateManager.java:666) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.14.RELEASE.jar:3.0.14.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1098) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.14.RELEASE.jar:3.0.14.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1072) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.14.RELEASE.jar:3.0.14.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.spring5.view.ThymeleafView.renderFragment(ThymeleafView.java:366) ~[thymeleaf-spring5-3.0.14.RELEASE.jar:3.0.14.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.spring5.view.ThymeleafView.render(ThymeleafView.java:190) ~[thymeleaf-spring5-3.0.14.RELEASE.jar:3.0.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1401) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1145) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1084) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:655) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:540) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:382) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:895) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1732) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]

2022-04-20 16:58:24.383 ERROR 3036 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] s.e.ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration$StaticView : Cannot render error page for request [/countries] and exception [An error happened during template parsing (template: "class path resource [templates/country.html]")] as the response has already been committed. As a result, the response may have the wrong status code.
```

Comment: I think your country id can be Long instead of Integer ?

Comment: It's not because even if I remove the country id and do the query using another data like the capital, I still get the same error message

Answer (score 0):

While rendering your template the id field in your country object can not be accessed.
You can try

```
<td th:text="${country.getId()}"></td>
```

instead.

Comment: I think the issues is from my mapping within the country and state class because am now getting this errors when I tried to only add data to the database. Hibernate: select country0_.id as id1_2_, country0_.capital as capital2_2_, country0_.code as code3_2_, country0_.continent as continen4_2_, country0_.description as descript5_2_, country0_.nationality as national6_2_ from country country0_           Hibernate: insert into country (capital, code, continent, description, nationality) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?). I don't know what to do to solve it. @Johannes

Comment: can you provide the code that does the insert and the full error log?

Comment: Insert and retrieve gives me the same error message which is this Caused by: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E: Property or field 'id' cannot be found on object of type 'com.elijah.profile.management.system.model.Country' - maybe not public or not valid?

Comment: I have edited the code, I added the service and repository class as well as updating the error from the log @Johannes

Comment: On a first sight it looks fine. How do you do your insert? with a input form or postman/direct api call?
2) Maybe you want to add a layer of abstraction by using DTOs to a) make your frontend independent from db changes and b) not to use db entities to render your template

Comment: Sorry for not reply for a while, my PC had a little issue which makes me not to be able to access the internet. I think the issue is from MYSQL database because everything was working perfectly until I made a little mistake from one of my table in the database and instead for me to delete that particular table, I dropped the whole database and when I created a new one for the project, that was when I started having the error "Property or field 'id' cannot be found on object of type 'com.elijah.profile.management.system.model.Country' - maybe not public or not valid?"

Comment: I don't know if you can suggest to me what could had lead to that because if i delete everything from the table, it will bring out the modal pop-up for me to fill the fields and when I click on the save button in which it supposed to save all the data into the table, it will be saved but when I check the database,it's only the id that is there because it was Autoincrement while the rest columns will be showing null.After adding the data into the table, the modal pop-up will not show again if you click on it except you delete everything from the table again. I really need suggestions @Johannes

Comment: If everything is null either no data arrives inside the json or there is something wrong in between receiving and saving. Can you provide the modal that you use for sending your data to the api? In the meantime try debugging your code and check what arrives at your api. Also make sure that your name/ th:field tags in your input form correspond to the field names in country